# fetching data from table into datatable using ajax and spring boot

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I need flow of spring boot mvc backend for fetching data from table using ajax and that to be display in datatable.

I am getting data using ajax but its not getting dispplayed in datatable.What is issue that i am not getting.

Please if anyone knows then reply .

Thanks & Regards,
Priya

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: In datatable call of ajax send request and got response in json form thats its but when i defined columns with data its not showing anything so what would be the issue not getting.

Comment: without any code or error how can we help.